# Definition of paradigm, abstraction and metaphor

Tags: meaning, technical

UNIX based operating systems uses the concept of paradigm to identify everything from files, folders, hard drives, networking interfaces as files.

Also it uses the concept of abstraction to reduce down hardware, network interfaces, etc. into files.

Please explain these concepts in details to me.

Also please explain what is metaphor?

Comment: Have you looked these terms up in a dictionary? What does the dictionary say about them? What about this is confusing to you in regards to their application to UNIX? As to metaphor, are you also looking for that in relation to UNIX? If not, it may be better to ask a separate question... but, still... show us the work you've done already.

Comment: Are you sure this wouldn't fit better over at unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I know their dictionary meaning. Only I cannot relate it with UNIX. And in UNIX site the mod closed it as off topic. As such I m here

Comment: @BaardKopperud Yeah I am absolutely sure about it but the mods over there closed it s off topic and referred me here

Comment: Yes in Unix everything - including devices like hard-disk, keyboard, screen and printer - are file.  That means that the same system-calls can be used for everything - since everything are files.  This in turns means that the same commands can be used for every file.  You can use the same command to read the raw content on a hard-disk as you use to read a file...  You can use the same command you usually use to write text to a file, to write text to a printer...  Of course some "files" have limitation - for example, you can't read from a printer or write to the keyboard.

Comment: Then what is the difference between paradigm and abstraction?

Comment: Everything is a file is just a metaphor - it's not *really* so, a printer is clearly not really a file.  Abstraction in this case means that the Unix Operating System "hides the truth" from the user and the programs, by *pretending* that everything actually *are* files.  The truth is hidden, an what the system presents are a uniformed set of system-calls for accessing and manipulating files.  Since you access things as if they were files - through calls like **read** and **write** - you can say (or rather pretend) that they actually all *are* files.

Comment: Some "files" may not implement all the system-calls used by typical files - for example you can't **write** to the keyboard - but apart from this, the metaphor/illusion works well.

Comment: and paradigm, you didn't mention about that word

Comment: In this context, I would say "paradigm" is more the "idea" - to let everything be files.  "Abstraction" is how they actually implemented this idea in Unix - by hiding the complexity and differences between files, directories, devices, pipes, network-sockets and all; and instead show the user (and programs) a unified way to access all these *very different* things... namely as files - as if they all were actual files - using the same set of "file-related" system-calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are the best. I would strongly suggest to sum it all as an answer as this is a jewel of an information.

Answer (score 3):

First, some definitions:

> **Paradigm** *noun*
> 1.1 A world view underlying the theories and methodology of a particular scientific subject
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paradigm)
>
> **Abstraction**
> In software engineering and computer science, abstraction is a technique for managing complexity of computer systems. It works by establishing a level of complexity on which a person interacts with the system, suppressing the more complex details below the current level.
> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering))
>
> **Metaphor**
> 1.1 A thing regarded as representative or symbolic of something else
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metaphor)

In the case of UNIX, the paradigm refers to the philosophy underlying the design of the system:

> The Unix philosophy, originated by Ken Thompson, is a set of cultural norms and philosophical approaches to minimalist, modular software development.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)

Here, *abstraction* refers to use of a uniform interface to access all I/O (input/output) devices. The complexity regarding the differences between handling keyboards and hard drives is implemented at a lower layer, but they all appear as *files* to higher layers.

As Baard Kopperud notes, these 'files' aren't literal files. The term *file* is simply a convenient label that references something more familiar. In particular, the term refers to things ('real' files) that can be opened and closed, read from and written to, etc. Hence calling the abstractions *files* employs a figure of speech - in this case, a *metaphor*.

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX everything is considered to be a file. This idea is called *paradigm.*

*Abstraction* is the way they actully implement this idea.

Everything is file is a *metaphor,* they are not actually all files. For example, a printer is not a file.

**CREDIT:** All credits goes to Baard Kopperud